# Rendering a label for multiple dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, semantic-ui-react

I have a multi dropdown select that lets you chose food item,s then when clicked you can add a text value to the end.  I'm using 'semantic-UI-react' for the Dropdown component.  My problem is that when I add the new value to my nested object, the label disappears. I can set either the label or nested object with the desired values, but when I try to do it together,  the label always disappears.  Pics for reference [image: dropdown]

[image: dropdown 2]

This is my code for it working this way:

```
const renderLabel = (item, i, { value }) => ({
    content: value,
    onClick: (e) => {
      const servingSize = prompt(value + ' serving size:');
      if (servingSize !== null) {
        value = item.text + ' ' + servingSize;
        e.target.firstChild.textContent = value;
      };
    }
  });

<Dropdown clearable id="breakfast-fruits1" renderLabel={renderLabel} search allowAdditions onAddItem={handleAddition} className="dropdown" placeholder="Fruits" fluid multiple selection options={fruits} onChange={handleChange} />
```

When I try to set state the last label disappears.

```
const renderLabel = (item, i, { value }) => ({
    content: value,
    onClick: (e) => {
      const servingSize = prompt(value + ' serving size:');
      if (servingSize !== null) {
        value = item.text + ' ' + servingSize;
        e.target.firstChild.textContent = value;
        setResult((prevResult) => {
          prevResult.monday.breakfast.fruits[i] = value;
          return prevResult;
        })
      };
    }
  });
```

Any ideas on how to make it work or set up better?  I have tried many different ways to render the label and change the state/result.  Let me know if I can include anything else in the question to make it more solvable.

Here is my fruits state:

```
const [ fruits, setFruits ] = useState([
    { key: 'Apple', text: 'Apple', value: 'Apple' },
    { key: 'Apricot', text: 'Apricot', value: 'Apricot' },
    { key: 'Banana', text: 'Banana', value: 'Banana' },
    { key: 'Berries', text: 'Berries', value: 'Berries' },
    { key: 'Blackberries', text: 'Blackberries', value: 'Blackberries' },
    { key: 'Blueberries', text: 'Blueberries', value: 'Blueberries' },
    { key: 'Cantaloupe', text: 'Cantaloupe', value: 'Cantaloupe' },
    { key: 'Cherries', text: 'Cherries', value: 'Cherries' },
    { key: 'Grapefruit', text: 'Grapefruit', value: 'Grapefruit' },
    { key: 'Honeydew', text: 'Honeydew', value: 'Honeydew' },
    { key: 'Kiwi', text: 'Kiwi', value: 'Kiwi' },
    { key: 'Melon', text: 'Melon', value: 'Melon' },
    { key: 'Nectarine', text: 'Nectarine', value: 'Nectarine' },
    { key: 'Orange', text: 'Orange', value: 'Orange' },
    { key: 'Papaya', text: 'Papaya', value: 'Papaya' },
    { key: 'Peach', text: 'Peach', value: 'Peach' },
    { key: 'Pear', text: 'Pear', value: 'Pear' },
    { key: 'Pineapple', text: 'Pineapple', value: 'Pineapple' },
    { key: 'Plum', text: 'Plum', value: 'Plum' },
    { key: 'Raspberries', text: 'Raspberries', value: 'Raspberries' },
    { key: 'Strawberries', text: 'Strawberries', value: 'Strawberries' },
    { key: 'Tangerine', text: 'Tangerine', value: 'Tangerine' },
    { key: 'Watermelon', text: 'Watermelon', value: 'Watermelon' }
  ]);
```

Here is my onChange function:

```
const handleChange = (e, { value }) => {
    const newData = update(result, {
      monday: {breakfast: {fruits: {$set: value}}}
    });
    setResult(newData);
  };
```

Here is my handleAddition function:

```
const handleAddition = (e, data) => {
    console.log(data.value);
    setFruits((prevFruits) => {
      return [
        ...prevFruits,
        { text: data.value, key: data.value, value: data.value }
      ];
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest breaking up the issue in 2 separate parts: `renderLabel` should only render label and return JSX to show on screen, and let's define a new function that handles the state updating. Render label can handle updating the new visuals if we can get the state updating functioning.

Let's begin.

Here the `renderLabel` function should have a single purpose, which is to display the label when the React component renders and re-renders.

In your code snippet number 2, it looks like you are trying to use a React Hook `setResult` to change the state of the app. It is recommended to define a separate function called e.g. `onLabelClick`, which then takes care of updating the state.

**UPDATE**

I wrote a CodePen on the issue and tested the functionality of your code.
You can take a look at [My CodePen Dropdown Test](https://codepen.io/emutanen/pen/MWbNgEK) It seems that when the option value is changed the text changes, too. These changes are not saved in options object.

I did not solve the problem, let's see if CodePen helps.

**About state management**

Finally, the code snippet 2 mutates the state of prevState, which is an antipattern in state updating systems. Always copy the previous state and merge with new substate, for example using

```
const newState = {...prevState, nameOfTheProperyToOverrideInPrevState: newValue};
```

this can prevent bugs in the app. Some popular state management systems are e.g.

- Redux
- Functional components using Hooks state
- Immutable.js

Reading about how they work can help realise why state updating can fail in more depth.

Comment: Yes, I definitely believe it is failing trying to update the state.  I have tried to make a copy like the way you have showed above.  I have also tried update with 'immutability-helper' and still the label disappears.  It does update state correctly, but anytime state is updated the render label disappears.  The renderLabel function you have provided does render the labels properly. Do you have any other suggestions on how I should try to solve this problem?  Just so you know yes, there is a setResult hook.

Comment: Thanks for trying it out! I would need to see more code to be able to pinpoint the issue, especially how you have defined options={fruits}. It seems that you are trying to edit the value of the label `option`, and saving that information by overwriting the existing value. Can we make the options={fruits} dynamic and immutable in the way that you don't overwrite prevState, but, instead copy and set new state, then drop/pass it to the options property?

Comment: Fruits is a state, which is an array of objects ex: [{ key: 'apple', text: 'apple', value: 'apple' }, { key: 'banana', text: 'banana', value: 'banana' }].  I use the onChange to get the value of that into the result state and also use it to add additional food items that are not currently in the dropdown options.  What is the best way to share you more code?  I am new to stack, react, and coding in general.

Comment: I have added the additional code above. Let me know if you need anything else.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: I use the fruit options for all fruit dropdowns as you can see from the pictures.

Comment: @idkwhatimdoing I have updated the answer, and added CodePen. I recommend you try it out to demonstrate your problem in future. I believe the options should retain their portion size value even when they are deselected. Is that what you want? I am still not sure if this solves your issue. It seems like options are not updating after a portion size edit is being done.